# Run simple one file java program with oneline comandline invokation with dependency fething

Tags: java

Hello I would like to run a simple java program which is contained in one file.
`javac foo.java && java foo` is not suitable due to external dependencies, which have to be downloaded. Do you know a simple way to run it as a one-liner or fetch dependency in some sane way like `npm install dep` or `pip install dep`?

Comment: Maven, Gradle, or SBT are the package management and runners in the Java world

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You should show the results you get when you run this command, but you probably just need to make a runnable, stand-alone jarfile, which is discussed in many SO Q&A. _How_ you create the package is up to you, and this is where things like Maven, Gradle, Ant, or even IDEs come into play.

Comment: I know 2 of them, but ist there option to run it in "sane", not java way?

Comment: @jdv how can I show results of invofking comand which i don't know?

Comment: @majkrzak I don't understand the question. What is it you actually want to do. One presumes you are in control of foo.java, and the build system that creates the classes and bundles the dependencies. Configure those to make a stand-alone, runnable jarfile. There are also tools that make executables for platforms from a collection of classes and dependencies.

Comment: @majkrzak if you actually ran that command you show, what would it say? If there are missing "dependencies" (i.e., the Java runtime can not resolve classes referenced in your code, or the code your code references) it will issue an error message saying this.

Comment: @jdv `javac: file not found: foo.java`

Comment: @majkrzak you have a different problem unrelated to class dependencies or execution. You are unable to invoke `javac` and make a class, so the command line fails at the `&&`. This is why I stressed that you need to refocus on what question you are trying to ask. Tell us what you want to do, _show_ what you tried, and tell us the results. The Answers here only talk around your main problems, which is a working _compilation_ environment. Solve that before trying to sort out a working _runtime_ environment.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. This site is not ideal as a tutorial for getting a build and deployment environment setup when the internet is literally bursting with such tutorials.

Comment: @jdv your idea was wto invoke this command, even if it was obvous that foo.java does not exists...

Comment: @majkrzak the command is in _your_ question. It was not obvious at all that the source file did not exist. If this was a hypothetical question then **make that clear**. See [ask] for how to ask a good question.

Comment: @jdv if when seeing `foo` isn't it obvious for you that it is hypothetical case, I don't see any hope for you. I'm sorry.

Comment: @majkrzak you might want to try and keep things civil since _you_ are the one asking for help here. This site is about creating useful Q&A content for _everyone_ to use, now and in the future. It isn't just about _you_. For the record, during my many decades of development when working with a new project I use "Foo" and "Fnord" _all the time_ because it is rare that things are named correctly during initial development. Anyway: I am trying to help _you_ make this question into something useful for you and others, and I'm doing this for free. So maybe take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others gave you good but incomplete answers. So, I'll get it together and clarify it for you.

First identify your dependencyies on https://mvnrepository.com, then for each of it invoke: `mvn -DgroupId=goo -DartifactId=goo -Dversion=1.0 dependency:get` or `mvn  -Dartifact=goo:goo:1.0 dependency:get`

All your dependencies are now located in `$HOME/.m2` so you can list them formated properly with `find $HOME/.m2 -name "*.jar" -printf ":%p"`

To compile your program with it invoke `javac -cp .$(find $HOME/.m2 -name "*.jar" -printf ":%p") foo.java`

And run it with `java -cp .$(find $HOME/.m2 -name "*.jar" -printf ":%p") foo`

So to summarize, here is your oneliner:

```
mvn -DgroupId=goo -DartifactId=goo -Dversion=1.0 dependency:get \
&& javac -cp .$(find $HOME/.m2 -name "*.jar" -printf ":%p") foo.java \
&& java -cp .$(find $HOME/.m2 -name "*.jar" -printf ":%p") foo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have external dependencies, you need to compile your code with them.

```
javac -cp .:/path/to/*.jar foo.java
```

Then you can try running your class file, again using the same classpath to include the other classes you need

Typically, though Java applications are packaged and distributed as JAR files, not class files.

If you want just a standalone script, then you could look at using Groovy

Comment: If I would have ability to chose language I will stay far away from java

Comment: Groovy compiles into Java classes, but it runs in one line, which seems to be what you're asking for

Answer (score 0):

Java has a npm equivalent called Maven https://maven.apache.org/ with maven you can do `mvn clean install` once setup will do that.

Comment: how cound I install https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay/com.liferay.osgi.service.tracker.collections/3.0.7 for example?

Comment: you need to add the dependency to the pom file.   here is a tutorial https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: `mvn -DgroupId=... -DartifactId=... -Dversion=... dependency:get` is probably the answer

Comment: npm is the same you you have to add the dependencies to package.json, pom.xml is the same for maven.

Comment: in the aprtoach i showed in question, no package json is neaded

Comment: are you sure?  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install `By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json`